Windows 2022 server not installing some Nuget packages
Recently Migrated .NET Web API project to Windows 2022 Server Environment, when restoring nuget packages related to SaxonHE11s9apiExtensions it failed. I have installed all the frameworks needed to run the project.
Error I get is :
Error        DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:11.6
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(RepositorySystemSession session, DependencyRequest request)
at IKVM.Maven.Sdk.Tasks.MavenReferenceItemResolve.ResolveCompileDependencyGraph(IkvmMavenEnvironment maven, RepositorySystemSession session, IList1 repositories, IList1 items) in C:\w\ikvm-maven\src\IKVM.Maven.Sdk.Tasks\MavenReferenceItemResolve.cs:line 254
at IKVM.Maven.Sdk.Tasks.MavenReferenceItemResolve.ResolveReferences(IList1 repositories, IList1 items) in C:\w\ikvm-maven\src\IKVM.Maven.Sdk.Tasks\MavenReferenceItemResolve.cs:line 193
at IKVM.Maven.Sdk.Tasks.MavenReferenceItemResolve.Execute() in C:\w\ikvm-maven\src\IKVM.Maven.Sdk.Tasks\MavenReferenceItemResolve.cs:line 151
DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:11.6
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(RepositorySystemSession session, CollectRequest request)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(RepositorySystemSession session, DependencyRequest request)
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:jar:11.6
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(RepositorySystemSession , ArtifactDescriptorRequest , ArtifactDescriptorResult )
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(RepositorySystemSession session, ArtifactDescriptorRequest request)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DataPool , ArtifactDescriptorRequest , RepositorySystemSession , Dependency , Results , Args )
ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:pom:11.6 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(RepositorySystemSession session, Collection requests)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositorySystemSession session, ArtifactRequest request)

Have you tried answers for this question?

tried it, didnt work
